# How to change the space of the plot labels in plot_drid()

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am trying to plot a figure but the data is confidential so I cannot post it here, but I will add an example (not the best example but it is so you understand my problem)

```
country<-c("United Kingdom", "Germany", "Poland", "Spain", "Portugal", "France")
x<-as.numeric(c(13.4,25.1,10,15,12.1,21.8))
y<-as.numeric(c(124,112,176,124,109,143))
df<<-data.frame(country, x,y)

p1<-ggplot(data=df)+geom_bar(aes(x=country,y=x),stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()+ylab("x")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=20),l+theme(panel.background = element_blank())

p2<-ggplot(data=df)+geom_bar(aes(x=country,y=y),stat="identity")+
  coord_flip()+ylab("y")+
  theme(text=element_text(size=20)+theme(panel.background = element_blank())

plot_grid(p1,p2,align = "vh",labels = c("(a)","(b)"),label_size=19)
```

When I plot it I will get a figure like this

[image]

How can I move the plot labels ("(a)" and "(b)") so that they are not overlapping with the axis labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this end, you can use `hjust` and `vjust` inside `plot_grid()`function. For example, this worked for me:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(p1,p2,align = "vh",
                   labels = c("(a)","(b)"),
                   vjust = 1.1, 
                   hjust = -.05,
                   label_size = 19)
```

[image]